# How can a class inherit from a parameterized version of itself?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I saw a C# class `SomeClass` that was defined like

```
public class SomeClass : IComparable<SomeClass>, IEquatable<SomeClass>
{
   // ... 
}
```

and I'm wondering how to translate that into English. The way I understand it seems logically impossible. How can a class inherit from a parameterized version of itself? Also, is this a common design pattern?

Comment: It just means that `SomeClass` will implement the methods of `IComparable` and `IEquatable` that use `SomeClass` as a type in their signature.  Specifically `int CompareTo(SomeClass)` and `bool Equals(SomeClass)`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key is to recognize that it's not inheriting from (or implementing) a parameterized version of *itself*, but rather inheriting from (or implementing) *another* class or interface, and using itself as a generic parameter for that target type.

For example, `IComparable<T>` says that there will be a `CompareTo()` method that takes an object of type `T` as a parameter. So by implementing `IComparable<SomeClass>` you're simply guaranteeing that a method with that signature will exist on this class:

```
public class SomeClass : IComparable<SomeClass>
{
    public int CompareTo(SomeClass other)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

And yes, this is fairly common practice. Classes often implement the generic `IComparable<>` and `IEquatable<>` interfaces to show that they can be compared with other items of the same type. It's maybe also worth mentioning that enums in Java are declared as extending `Enum<>` of themselves--a pattern which is not *common* in C#, but does appear from time to time.

Comment: I don't see how this is "the key" at all. It's perfectly alright to inherit a parameterized version of oneself too, consider the following: `class Foo<T> { public T Value; } class Foo : Foo<int> { }` I'd say the key is realizing that `Foo` and `Foo<T>` are *not the same types* and so their inheriting eachother (although not both at the same time) is not weird at all.

Comment: @kai: `class Foo : Foo<int>` is not an example of the class inheriting from itself. As you say, those are two different types. If you had `class Foo<T> : Foo<T>` then it would be trying to inherit from itself, and that *would not* make sense, so the OP's concern is a valid one. Hence, the key is to recognize that `IComparable<SomeClass>` is not the same as `SomeClass`. In other words, it's not inheriting from or implementing itself, but another type entirely--it just happens to be passing itself as a generic parameter to that other type in this case.

Comment: What OP was speaking about was a *"parameterized version of itself"*, would you not describe `IEnumerable<int>` as a "parameterized version" of `IEnumerable`?

Comment: @kai: I could understand someone calling it that, in which case an appropriate answer would be to point out that `IEnumerable<>` and `IEnumerable` are actually two different types that just happen to share the same name. But I would certainly not describe `IEnumerable<int>` as a parameterized version of `int`, which is more along the lines of what the OP asked, don't you think?

Comment: yes, I agree, OP's question is not very well formed, so it's hard to deduce exactly what is asked for. I'd also like to note that I never said that `Foo : Foo<int>` was an example of a type inheriting itself, on the contrary, I made it perfectly clear that it was legal BECAUSE they are different types :)

Comment: Although I must admit that after rereading your answer I don't have any issues with it really, I was hasty. The key word I missed was "inheriting from (or implementing) *another* class or interface"

Comment: @kai: That's a good point. I'll emphasize that word to make the point clearer. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I think the given notation - `public class A : B<A>` (if B is a class, not interface!) - looks very confusing: we got used to think that something in the left part of expression is defined by something it the right part. So this notation is just mind-blowing, IMHO: because it looks like we are trying to define class A by... making use of class A :)

Comment: @Alexander: It might help to think of it like any other recursive definition (e.g. `int Fib(int i) => i <= 2 ? i - 1 : Fib(i-1) + Fib(i-2);`).

Comment: @striplingwarrior well... probably... although, if i see recursion - i know that in some moment as I dive deeper the result is a determined number and I am starting to emerge :) in case of a `class`... what is this "determined number"?

Answer (score 1):

Translated in "English" it means: "Boy (or girl), you'd better be type-safe when implementing those interfaces, especially IComparable. Otherwise, you'll have to perform type casting, which I guess you don't want"

See the code below. SomeClass implemented IComparable and IComparable.
See differencies between implementations of CompareTo(object) and CompareTo(SomeClass).

```
namespace InterfacesStuff
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var someClass1 = new SomeClass {ComparedValue = 1};
            var someClass2 = new SomeClass {ComparedValue = 2};

            //someClassObject defined as SomeClass
            //object someClassObject = new SomeClass { ComparedValue = 2 };

            //someClassObject defined as anything else but SomeClass
            object someClassObject = 5;

            int comparisonSomeClassBySomeClass = someClass1.CompareTo(someClass2);

            int comparisonSomeClassByObject = someClass1.CompareTo(someClassObject);
        }
    }


    public class SomeClass : IComparable, IComparable<SomeClass>, IEquatable<string>, IEquatable<int>,
        IEquatable<double>
    {
        public int ComparedValue;

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            var presumedSomeClassObject = obj as SomeClass;

            if (presumedSomeClassObject != null)
            {
                if (ComparedValue <= ((SomeClass) obj).ComparedValue)
                    return -1;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        public int CompareTo(SomeClass other)
        {
            if (ComparedValue <= other.ComparedValue)
                return -1;

            return 0;
        }

        public bool Equals(double other)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool Equals(int other)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool Equals(string other)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not Inheriting, It is implementing the `IComparable Interface`. what is going on is

`Someclass` Implements the `Icomparable` and the `IEquatable` interface. Implementing an interface is like signing a contract stating you gaurentee that this class will implement the methods on an interface.

[Icomparable msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx), [IEquatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx). If you look at the MSDN pages you can see that SomeClass gaurentees it will implement the methods in some fashion.

This is very common practice and it is many different names. The ones I hear most are `programming by contract` and `Implementation over Inhertience`. It lets you do a lot of cool things, like Dependency Injection, Proper Unit testing, better Generics. It does this because the compiler doesnt need to know the concrete class that your object is implementing. It just needs to know that it has certain functions on it.  For further reading on this I would read Chapter one of the gang of four Design pattern book.

[Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) Specifically  the Introduction to Chapter one section

Comment: This both does not answer the question, and argues semantics: an interface in C# is just a strict form of an abstract class with only abstract members and no state. Using the word "implements" instead of "inherits" doesn't really explain or change anything.

Comment: @kai I think you are completely wrong in your statement ` Using the word "implements" instead of "inherits" doesn't really explain or change anything` Saying thing X implements Y is the defacto standard. For example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx, that is the same verbage that microsoft uses when using an interface.

Comment: I know it's standard lingo, but it's not fundamentally different. implementation is just a strict form of inheritance, they share the same semantics and effects. The ONLY difference is that a class can inherit from several interfaces but only from one class. And it's still not at all related to the question.

Comment: @gh9: What kai's saying is that your answer is getting fixated on the use of the term "inherited" without really appearing to understand or address the question that the OP is trying to ask. If you were to replace the word "inherit" with "implement" in the OP, then you could capture the crux of what the question is trying to get to, and the answer to that question would have nothing to do with the difference between the two types of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted does not inherit from any class. It is implementing certain so-called Interfaces. How to translate that snippet: "I guarantee that SomeClass will be Comparable and equatable with other SomeClass instances. I will provide definitions in this class on how to do that."

About specializing a class from some other class...
What you can do is something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Pet
    {
        protected string name;
        public Pet(String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }

    class Dog : Pet
    {
        private List<String> tricks;
        public Dog(String name, List<String> tricks):base(name)
        {
            this.tricks = tricks;
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> tricks = new List<string>();
            tricks.Add("sit");
            tricks.Add("jump");
            tricks.Add("bark");
            Dog puppy = new Dog("Fido", tricks);
        }
    }
}
```

Dog inherits from Pet. Dog calls Pet's constructor at creation. Whatever name you pass into Dog constructor, it will forward it to Pet constructor. 
Because what happens is that a subclass first calls the constructor of its superclass with the appropriate arguments. Then it runs its own constructor. Whatever is declared as public or protected in a class will be visible to its subclasses.

Therefore Dog will have name and also a list of tricks:

[image: puppy object result]

You achieve this kind of view with the "Locals" window.

I recommend that you read some tutorials on c# [inheritance](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_inheritance.htm), [interfaces](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_interfaces.htm) and [generics](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_generics.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really have to be convenient to express it in english for it to be valid code, although I'd probably read that as "SomeClass is comparable and equatable to itself". That doesn't really explain what's going on though, it's just a way of expressing it.

In C# types can be *generic* over categories of other types. Generic types are basically "type constructors". They take other types as parameters, and use them to construct new types. For instance, `IEnumerable<int>` and `IEnumerable<string>` are *two completely different types*. The non-generic version (`IEnumerable`) is a third one. In C# a type `A` can inherit ANY other type `B` as long as none of the following is true (I hope I didn't miss anything):

- B is already a subtype of A
- B is a class and A has already inherited another class
- B is a struct
- A is an interface but B is not
- A is the same type as B
- B is sealed
- A is a struct and B is not an interface

This even makes the following code legal:

```
class Foo<T>
{
    public T Value;
}

class Foo : Foo<int>
{
}
```

`Foo` and `Foo<T>` are different types, so there's no problem at all for one to inherit the other.

You can read more about generics here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

And about inheritance here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx